# How to find any text in a event error in Bugsnag?

Tags: logging, monitoring, bugsnag

I need to find by any text in a Bugsnag event, but filter dashboard not offer this option.

How to find any text by stacktrace, request, device or metadata informations in Bugsnag?

Comment: I have the same issue. It has been a year since you asked, did you find an answer? Did you ask Bugsnag support? Would it be easier having our error messages on local database?

Comment: How to find exception in Bugsnag by exception message?

Comment: Hi. Bugsnag suggests by custom filter. See https://docs.bugsnag.com/product/custom-filters/

Comment: To get database errors use Bugsnag API, https://docs.bugsnag.com/api/data-access/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bugsnag's dashboard has powerful [search and segmentation](https://docs.bugsnag.com/product/searching-dashboard/#search-box) options. You can filter for specific text in the event Stacktrace, Environment (including device info), and any custom metadata that you attach using [Custom Filters](https://docs.bugsnag.com/product/custom-filters/).